# How to overload __str__ operation so str("test") returns "test"

Tags: python, string, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the **str** operation so that when I do str(string) it keeps the quotations.

ex:
str("test")
returns test

I want it to return "test"

Heres what I have written, any help would be very much appreciated!

```
class Action(MalmoAgent):
    def __init__(self, command = '', value = 0):
        self.__command =  command
        self.__value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return ' " ' + self + ' " '
```

Comment: I'm confused ... What does `str("test")` have to do with your custom class `Action`?

Comment: `str("test")` already does return `"test"`, so even that part of your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr()`, this is obviously not an actual string.

```
repr('Test')
```

Comment: This won't work if the OP expects `'Test'` and `"Test"` to remain distinct.

Comment: He can of course change the content, I only aimed to show him how to keep the quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Just format your string

```
...  def __str__(self):
...   return '"%s"' % self.whatever
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Could you explain your potential solution? why would I use the mod operator?

Comment: @ArcherGreenhalgh It's not a *mod operator* here, its used as a string format operation. Read more about it here : https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

```
class MalmoAgent():
    pass

class Action(MalmoAgent):
    def __init__(self, command='', value=0):
        self.__command = command
        self.__value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '"' + super(Action, self).__str__() + '"'


thing = Action()

print("I have a", thing, "called thing.")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I have a "<__main__.Action object at 0x101ae9a90>" called thing.
```